# Can the Badges tab of user profile display unviewed badge count?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, notifications

The Reputation and Response tabs headings display the number of unviewed items/score for that tab.

Can something similar be done for badges?

Specifically, if I have just earned two badges since viewing the badge tab, a little blue square with a white number "2" appears on the tab at the word "badges"